# qemu3.0.0をつかってkbcの割り込みを使うとqemuが再起動する

Tags: c, assembly, qemu, x86

ubuntu18で自作OSを作っています。
[この方](http://yuma.ohgami.jp/)の「フルスクラッチで作る!x86_64自作OS」を読んで自分で書いてみているのですが、4章のkbcの割り込みを実装しqemu3.0.0をつかって起動させ実際にキーボードで適当に打つとqemuの再起動（OVMFの画面であるtianocoreのロゴが出てくる）がかかります。
具体的なソースは[こちら](https://github.com/cupnes/x86_64_jisaku_os_samples/tree/master/040_intr)の方のものを使用しています。

また、手持ちのノートパソコン(ubuntu18)を使って、aptで入れた古いバージョン(2.4)を使うとkbcの割り込みが起こり、文字が表示されます。
ソースではkbc以外の割り込みは無限ループになるようにかかれているのでkbc以外の割り込みが起きているとも考えにくいのですが